# Custom field not sends thought additional_data in custom payment method on checkout of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have a custom payment method which has a field. But I can't pass this field value to additional_data when submitting this payment. Here is code:

.../app/code/Test/Custompayment/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer.js

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
],
function (
    Component,
    rendererList
) {
    'use strict';
    rendererList.push(
        {
            type: 'custompayment',
            component: 'Test_Custompayment/js/view/payment/method-renderer/custompayment'
        }
    );
    return Component.extend({
        getData: function() {
            return {
                'method': this.item.method,
                'additional_data': {
                    'test': this.test()
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
);
```

.../app/code/Test/Custompayment/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/custompayment.js

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
],
function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Test_Custompayment/payment/custompayment'
        }
    });
}
);
```

.../app/code/Test/Custompayment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/custompayment.html

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
<div class="payment-method-title field choice">
    <input type="radio"
           name="payment[method]"
           class="radio"
           data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
    <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
</div>
<div class="payment-method-content">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
    <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>

    <form class="form" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '-form'}">
        <fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items ccard ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}">
            <label for="custompayment_test">CC email(s)</label><input type="text" name="payment[test]" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()+'_test'}">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button class="action primary checkout"
                    type="submit"
                    data-bind="
                    click: placeOrder,
                    attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                    css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                    enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                    "
                    disabled>
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...app/code/Test/Custompayment/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="custompayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Sellry_Custompayment/js/view/payment/method-renderer</item>
                                                                <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="custompayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

.../app/code/Test/Custompayment/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <payment>
        <custompayment>
            <model>Test\Custompayment\Model\PaymentMethod</model>
            <active>1</active>
            <title>Custom PO</title>
            <order_status>pending</order_status><!-- set default order status-->
        </custompayment>
    </payment>
</default>
```

Any idea what I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add method `getData()` to your js method renderer `payment/method-renderer/custompayment.js`:

```
getData: function () {
    var data = {
        method: this.getCode(),
        additional_data: {
            myField: $('#myFieldId').val()
        }
    };

    return data;
}
```

then you should create observer `PaymentAdditionalDataAssignObserver` to assign this data to payment additional information:

```
namespace Test\Custompayment\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Observer\AbstractDataAssignObserver;

class PaymentAdditionalDataAssignObserver extends AbstractDataAssignObserver
{
    const MY_FIELD_NAME_INDEX = 'myField';

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $data = $this->readDataArgument($observer);

        $additionalData = $data->getData(PaymentInterface::KEY_ADDITIONAL_DATA);
        if (!is_array($additionalData) || !isset($additionalData[self::MY_FIELD_NAME_INDEX])) {
            return; // or throw exception depending on your logic
        }

        $paymentInfo = $this->readPaymentModelArgument($observer);
        $paymentInfo->setAdditionalInformation(
            self::MY_FIELD_NAME_INDEX,
            $additionalData[self::MY_FIELD_NAME_INDEX]
        );
    }
}
```

and then describe this observer in your etc/events.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_assign_data_custompayment">
        <observer name="custompayment_payment_data_assign"
                  instance="Test\Custompayment\Observer\PaymentAdditionalDataAssignObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

I haven't tested it so there may be some typos.